# Search date between two cells and return a third cell value

Tags: excel, vlookup

I Have two separate tables:

```
Start       End        Number
12/10/2017  31/10/2019  4
1/11/2019   28/02/2020  5
1/03/2020   1/12/2025   6
```

Also

```
Value   Date     Multiplication
45  1/11/2017
124 1/04/2018
43  1/09/2018
123 1/02/2019
46  1/07/2019
76  1/12/2019
789 1/05/2020
```

I want the Multiplication column to be populated by `Value * Number` based on if the date is between Stand and End

e.g.

Since 1/11/2017 is between 12/10/2017 & 31/10/2019 the values should be , 45*4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with the following sample data image, try this in H2:

```
=F2*VLOOKUP(G2, A$2:C$4, 3, TRUE)
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image]